# How to launch a command at the start of each vite build?

Tags: vite, vercel, sveltekit

I am using SvelteKit 1.5.0 with Vite 4.2.0 and Vercel as a SSR server.

I have multiple markdown files that I would like to build an index during each build,

This would allow me or other editors to edit markdown files, push to Github & trigger a build on Vercel that would every time prepare the list of pages and each page ready on the server-side.

**How can I run a command at the start of each vite build ?** In this case, the command would allow me to build that index & prepare the pages.

(I built an alternative with a serverless function that lists markdown files in a folder and loads each markdown file at page load but I experienced slowness so I would like to try if this way is faster)

Answer (score 3):

You could just add a plugin in the Vite config that has a [`buildStart` hook](https://vitejs.dev/guide/api-plugin.html#universal-hooks).

Not sure if the hook will always trigger, if so and you do not want to run the operation when running the dev server, you can check the `command` that Vite was run with:

```js
// vite.config.js

export default defineConfig(({ command }) => ({
    // ...
    plugins: [
        // ...
        {
            name: 'build-index',
            async buildStart(options) {
                if (command == 'serve')
                    return;

                // <logic>
            },
        },
    ],
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Very close to @H.B.'s answer, this is what worked for me:

```js
// vite.config.js

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig(({ command }) => {
  return {
    // ...
    plugins: [
      // ...
      {
        name: 'build-script',
        buildStart(options) {
          if (command === 'build') {
            // <logic>
          }
        },
      },
    ],
  }
})
```

Comment: That should be completely equivalent.